# Anti-commutator version of Zassenhaus formula

Tags: quantum-mechanics, lie-algebra, linear-algebra, anticommutator

The [Zassenhaus formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula) goes like 
$$
e^{t(X+Y)}= e^{tX}~ e^{tY} ~e^{-\frac{t^2}{2} [X,Y]} ~
e^{\frac{t^3}{6}(2[Y,[X,Y]]+ [X,[X,Y]] )} ~
e^{\frac{-t^4}{24}([[[X,Y],X],X] + 3[[[X,Y],X],Y] + 3[[[X,Y],Y],Y]) } \cdots,
$$
where $X$ and $Y$ are operators may not commute.

> Do people know and derive the anti-commutator version of  Zassenhaus formula that expresses in terms of anti-commutator $\{X,Y\}$ in a very compact form?

I haven't found it on the literature (yet).

(1) Let us consider Grassmann-parity of $X$ and $Y$ are both even, so that $X$ and $Y$ both contain even number of fermionic operators $f/f^\dagger$, where
$$
\{f_i,f_j^\dagger\}=\delta_{ij}
$$

(2) What if $X$ or $Y$ contain an odd number of fermionic operators?

Comment: Such an expansion is (in general) impossible.

Comment: There cannot be any such general formula unless you specify some special properties of $X$ and $Y$. The formula for a commutator exists because it is associated with adjoint action of a group.

Comment: What's the Grassmann-parity of $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: Let us consider Grassmann-parity of X and Y are both even.

Comment: $\{f_i,f_j^\dagger\}=\delta_{ij}$ is then not relevant for $\{X,Y\}$.

Comment: In that even parity case, one can expand in terms of the sub-operators.